# How to count cells that are below a certain date and check if other cells in the current row are empty?

Tags: google-sheets

I need to count how many cells in a specific column are below a certain date. Also, at the same time, the counter should only be increased, if some other cells next to each cell being counted are empty.

Example

Columns:

```
Date1          Date2            Date3
01/02/2012     01/02/2012       01/02/2012
01/02/2012     01/02/2012       01/02/2012
01/02/2012     01/02/2012       01/02/2012
               01/02/2012       
               01/02/2012       
01/02/2012     01/02/2012       01/02/2012
```

I need to count how many cells in the column Date2 are below some date AND where date1 + date3 are empty. The result would be: 2

Currently, i only know how to count the number of cells below a certain date:

```
=COUNTIF(ArrayFormula(Mona!$F$4:$F$400); "<="&$AY12)
```

But this doesnt work with the other criteria :(

I am using google-docs

**REAL DATA**

Columns:

```
B         C          D            E
```

I need to count the number of cells where C is below AY12, and where B, D and E are empty ("")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the question asks for a count of rows where the date is before AY12 and the other columns are blank (not populated). It's simpler to "nest" the IF statements, I think - I'd use this version

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(if(Mona!$C$4:$C$400<=$AY12,if(Mona!$B$4:$B$400="",if(Mona!$D$4:$D$400="",if(Mona!$E$4:$E$400="",1))))))`

Note that blank cells in column C will also be deemed to be <=AY12 so if those might be blank too then you might want to add a check to ensure that that column is not blank, i.e.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(if(Mona!$C$4:$C$400<=$AY12,if(Mona!$C$4:$C$400<>"",if(Mona!$B$4:$B$400="",if(Mona!$D$4:$D$400="",if(Mona!$E$4:$E$400="",1)))))))`

Replace commas with semi-colons if your version requires it

Note that your COUNTIF formula quoted above doesn't need the "Arrayformula" part, can simply be this

`=COUNTIF(Mona!$F$4:$F$400;"<="&$AY12)`

Answer (score 3):

In Excel you'd use `=countifs()`, rather than `=countif()`

You could emulate it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(if(if(Mona!$F$4:$F$400<=$AY12,1,0)+if(Mona!$E$4:$E$400<>"",1,0)+if(Mona!$D$4:$D$400<>"",1,0)=3,1,0)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What does the ,1,0 and =3,1,0 do?

I will edit my question with the real data, would you perhaps be so kind as to edit your answer according to this?

Comment: Jon is using 3 inner if statements. In the first case he is checking to see if it is < AY2 if it is it as given value of 1. He also checks two different columns for blank values. If a cell is blank it is given a value of 1. He then adds those 3 values together. If he gets a result of 3, he sets the final value to 1.  if he doesn't have a value of 3, he sets the final value to 0.